# Real-time views count- logging to a .txt in a user folder

Tags: php, ajax

I've got this code that logs to a .txt file in a user folder. I need it to refresh in real time or 1 or 5 seconds.

The code basically logs a visitor that viewing the page, so it will say: Viewers: 1 and when the visitor exit the page it will go back to Viewers: 0

The script is working but I want it to refresh.

Any ideas?
Here the PHP Code:

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';
if ($_GET[user] != ""){

$check_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE username='$lowerusername'");

  while ($display = mysql_fetch_array($check_query)) {
      $username = $display['username'];
  }}

 $dataFile = "profile/$username/visitors.txt";

$sessionTime = 1; //this is the time in **minutes** to consider someone online before removing them from our file

//Please do not edit bellow this line

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if(!file_exists($dataFile)) {
    $fp = fopen($dataFile, "w+");
    fclose($fp);
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$users = array();
$onusers = array();

//getting
$fp = fopen($dataFile, "r");
flock($fp, LOCK_SH);
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $users[] = rtrim(fgets($fp, 32));
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);


//cleaning
$x = 0;
$alreadyIn = FALSE;
foreach($users as $key => $data) {
    list( , $lastvisit) = explode("|", $data);
    if(time() - $lastvisit >= $sessionTime * 10) {
        $users[$x] = "";
    } else {
        if(strpos($data, $ip) !== FALSE) {
            $alreadyIn = TRUE;
            $users[$x] = "$ip|" . time(); //updating
        }
    }
    $x++;
}

if($alreadyIn == FALSE) {
    $users[] = "$ip|" . time();
}

//writing
$fp = fopen($dataFile, "w+");
flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
$i = 0;
foreach($users as $single) {
    if($single != "") {
        fwrite($fp, $single . "\r\n");
        $i++;
    }
}
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
fclose($fp);

if($uo_keepquiet != TRUE) {
    echo '<strong>Viewers:</strong> ' . $i . '';
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question actually is.  Is your code not working? If so then how have you setup it up to run and what errors are being thrown.  Help us to help you.

Comment: Sorry it is working just need it to refresh every 5 second or auto refresh, i'll edit the post.

Comment: You can work much easier with everything when you don't mix PHP (logic) and HTML (view). Also consider using an in-memory database as file writes use IO and are blocking.

Comment: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> - putting this in the head of your html, you get page refresh after 5 sec